# Install an ODBC driver on Windows without admin rights

Tags: windows, drivers, odbc, non-admin

Is it possible to install an ODBC driver on Windows 10 without admin rights?

I have SQLiteODBC driver, which is a single dll file. I want to be able to use it without touching any privileged areas. In other words, I want to keep the driver in a user directory, and the necessary registry settings can only go into HKCU key.

Further, while I am on Windows x64, I use both x32 and x64 ODBC clients. The system settings go to HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC for x64 drivers and to HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC for x32 drivers. In HKCU, I see just one key HKCU\Software\ODBC, and I wonder if and how it can be used to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you install the driver normally, or try to do it differently via the Registry, you need to have Admin rights or Domain Admin rights if the workstation is on a server.

Regular users cannot install ODBC themselves but if properly installed and set up, regular users can use ODBC in (say) Excel or whatever uses ODBC.

I have done this for users.